# How to remove webpack integration from jHipster project?

Tags: webpack, jhipster

I want to remove Webpack from a jHipster project I generated. I am not familiar with it and don't want to learn it at this time. Is it possible to just remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove it, you won't be able to build and run the angular part.